# Writing to new file

Tags: java, file-io

I am using FileOutputStream for writing some data to a file. Every time I execute my program, it appends the data to existing file instead of creating new one. I want to create a new file every time I execute the program. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't append by default. It will only append when you use the [constructor of `FileOutputStream` taking a boolean argument](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) wherein you pass `true`. Just [remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) it.

In a nut, don't do

```
output = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

but rather do

```
output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, I believe it overwrites. Are you by any chance calling

```
new FileOutputStream(name, true)
```

? If so, just change `true` to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream("myfile");
```

would create a new file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the FileOutputStream constructor accepts a second parameter. It is a boolean where *false* will cause file overwrite.